# Eclipse shortcuts on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, shortcut

please teach me some shortcuts

1. line swapping with above or below
2. rename variables consistent which has same names
   (It's Alt+Shift+R on windows Eclipse)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this [cheat sheet](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/developer-tools/dislikes/eclipse/osx-keyboard-binding-cheat-sheet/) for eclipse on mac os.
Very easy to find by just searching for **eclipse shortcuts mac cheat sheet** on google ;-)
(so don't hesitate to use google)

Comment: Thanks, But the short cuts never works, maybe it's eclipse problem. but, actually the cheat-sheet will be help for me

Comment: I'm affraid this link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Not a great link. For instance: Maximize Active View/Editor ⌘ M Editor Maximizes active view/editor does not work. Instead need to use control M to maximize, and minimize.

Comment: Hah and this became the first link on Google. Talk about users driving content!

Comment: @krisnik https://web.archive.org/web/20130119030805/http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/developer-tools/dislikes/eclipse/osx-keyboard-binding-cheat-sheet/